# Como ampliar el tamaño de una celda en boostrap table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

Hola Tengo una tabla usando bootstrap table y necesito que el TH sea mas largo a o sea el width.

Estoy intentando con la propiedad data-width="35%" pero no le logrado nada, puede alguien orientarme?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la propiedad **colspan**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Tu th</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contenido</td>
    <td>Contenido</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: En efecto cambia bien el tamaño, pero los TD correspondiente al TH  se quedan del mismo tamaño, pense que cambiando de tamaño el TH cambiaria tambien toda la columna

Comment: No, para cambiar los TD tienes que ponerles también esa propiedad a cada uno de los que quieras cambiar.

Comment: El problema es que estoy usando bootstrap table y los TD se generan cuando cargo los datos

Comment: has probado quitando el porcentaje?... y que solo quede asi:    data-width="35"

Comment: lo hice pero nada aun la columna ni se mueve